# How to configure MariaDB(self hosted in EC2) storage on an EBS volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-ebs

I have installed MariaDB on an EC2 instance. EC2 instance is small in size as our product is in development phase and we have very less traffic.

I want to keep an EBS volume for MariaDB data storage, so that as our traffic increases we can attach the EBS volume to a bigger EC2 instance and my data get transferred automatically.

1. Is keeping data storage on EBS(network) is a good approach? Will it not lead to more latent read/write?
2. If it won't impact my performance, what is the way to configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An EC2 instance is made of 2 things - Compute & Storage.

Storage is basically an EBS volume (kind of Hard Disk of your laptop) that includes your OS files as well as other files for the software installed on your EC2.

Since, you are running your database on an EC2 instance, this EBS volume will also store your MariaDB database files on the same EBS where your OS is installed. It is not like, you can store MariaDB data on some other EBS.

So, when your data grows, you can expand EBS volume of your existing EC2 instance. You can follow this tutorial to learn how to do that - [Increase the size of an Amazon EBS volume on an EC2 instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/modify-ebs-volume-on-instance.html)

Second thing is about performance. If your traffic increases, and you feel, you need more processing power (RAM or CPU), in that case you can upgrade your instance family. Refer this to see how to do that - [Change the instance type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html).

### Recommendation

As you will be spending a fixed monthly cost to run the EC2, my recommendation would be to use [Aurora Serverless v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.html) with minimum capacity you need initially. Later, it can automatically scale itself when the traffic grows.

Comment: Thanks Ankush this helped me to decide